# Potential on a charged plate

Tags: electrostatics, potential, conductors

We all know that at any point potential can be defined.
When we say a capacitor is charged to a certain potential we mean that the plates acquired some charge, having a potential difference between the two plates (in the case of parallel plate capacitor) equal to the potential difference of battery.

So my question is:

- What is the potential of any point ***on the surface*** of a charged plate?
- Is the charged plate an equipotential?

As we know, the electric field of infinite plate is $\sigma/2\epsilon_{0}$ and is equal to $dV/dR$.
Can we use this to say that potential **on the surface of the charged plate** is infinite?

Comment: Yes, an infinite plate, with an infinite charge would have an infinite potential relative to a zero point chosen at infinity.

Comment: Do the practical application of potential on a infinite plate is not worthy that's why we usually ignore to talk about that on the conductor. And only see the difference between the two plates.